# get 24 hours records in sqlalchemy extract

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a task to count number of records in a specific time and also split that data in every hour using sqlalchemy, for that I used `extract` in sqlalchemy

the table `Shapes` has three columns - ID, name, timestamp

```
output = self.session.query(db.Shapes.name, 
            extract('day', db.Shapes.timestamp).label('day'),
            extract('hour', db.Shapes.timestamp).label('hour'),
            func.count(db.Shapes.name).label("total_records"),
            )\
        .filter(db.Shapes.timestamp.between(from_datetime, to_datetime))\
        .group_by('hour')\
        .all()
```

`timestamp` is the `DateTime` object which handle python datatime objects in the format of '2022-08-15 14:45:21'

this returns the data like this, if i give the `from_datetime`, `to_datetime` as today date

```
[('circle', 15, 3, 10)]
```

but how to get the data for every hour without `for` loop, like this

```
[
('circle', 15, 1, 0), 
('circle', 15, 2, 0),
('circle', 15, 3, 10), 
('circle', 15, 4, 0),
....
....
('circle', 15, 23, 0), 
('circle', 15, 24, 0),
]
#where all the total_records have 0 if there is no data in that specific hour
```

how to achieve this in sqlalchemy, thanks

Comment: but which database are you using? PostgreSQL? MySQL? SQL Server? …?

Comment: @GordThompson, I am using ms sql server and also in sqlite3

Comment: Shouldn't your query also `.group_by(db.Shapes.name)` and `.group_by('day')` in order to run ?

Comment: @edg, i tried using `.group_by('day')` which returns the date which is only in the tabel, if there is no record on hour 5, it is not return the result with hour 5 has 0 count